# Как работать с апи если сайт требует SSL сертификат?

Tags: python, ssl, devops

У меня есть некая программа для работы с апи DevOps. Получение данных с одного DevOps и создание user story/tasks  в другом. Функция получения данных будет ниже.
Но недавно нам сказали установить SSL сертификат и заходить в девопс теперь можно только через VPN компании. Соответственно, теперь появляется такая ошибка. Я совсем не знаю куда двигаться

> raise SSLError(e, request=request)

> requests.exceptions.SSLError:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='devops.xregernd.local', port=443): Max retries
> exceeded with url:
> /Support/Maergt/_apis/wit/workitems/$User%20Story?api-version=5.1
> (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL:
> CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get
> local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1122)')))

```
def GetUSInfo(id_):

url_get_m = f'http://devops.xpa123re.com:8181/support/Mat/_apis/wit/workitems/{id_}?api-version=5.1'

r = requests.get(url_get_m,
    auth=(user_name_x, token_x))
res = r.json()

workType = res['fields']['System.WorkItemType']

if workType != "User Story":
    return False, False, False, "Not a User Story"
id_ = res['id']
title = res['fields']['System.Title']
description = res['fields']['System.Description']
return id_, title, description, "OK"
```

Comment: Используй urllib, мне помогло.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В библиотеке `requests` по умолчанию включена проверка SSL сертификатов как в браузере. В вашем случае проверка не удалась, получили ошибку `SSLError` - `unable to get local issuer certificate`. Для более глубокого понимания вопроса, Вам стоит прочитать про SSL сертификаты.

В `request` для отключения проверки сертификата используется передача соответствующего параметра `verify = False`:

```
requests.get(url, verify=False)
```

Для передачи сертификата:

```
requests.get(url, verify='/path/to/certfile')
# или в сессии
session = requests.Session()
session.verify = '/path/to/certfile'
```

Для получения сертификата для библиотеки `request` можно использовать [certifi](https://pypi.org/project/certifi/).

```
import certifi
certifi.where()  # out: '/path/to/python_dir/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem'
```

Comment: спасибо за certifi!

Comment: мне интересно решит ли данный ответ проблему ТС. Все-таки все поиски в интернете приводят к данному решению. Да, и при установке `requests` `certifi` прилетает вместе. Мне кажется, что здесь может быть проблема из-за самой политики компании, которая может предоставлять доступ по самоподписаным сертификатам и выдавать сотрудникам. Тут `verify = False` и манипуляции с `certifi` не сработают.

Comment: @Дмитрий спасибо за поправку с импортом certifi, по поводу вопроса, в ошибке явно сказано что не найден локальный сертификат, по-этому я думаю, как минимум надо проделать эти действия, потом плясать дальше если не поможет)

Comment: Спасибо, verify=False помог. Я уже видел это решение в интернете, но магическим образом в прошлый раз это не работало.

Comment: А что делать с requests.patch() ? Там got an unexpected keyword argument 'vefiry'